# adding columns with different indicies results in NaN

Tags: python, pandas, nan

my df:

```
   df = pd.DataFrame({'p1_profit': {0: -196.50000000000023,
      1: -593.73000000000025,
      2: -712.46000000000026,
      3: -657.88000000000011,
      4: -763.18000000000029},
     'p2_profit': {0: -634.36999999999989,
      1: -737.14999999999998,
      2:  224.41999999999985,
      3: -697.20000000000005,
      4: -526.78999999999996},
     'p3_profit': {0: 211.32999999999981,
      1: -155.02000000000021,
      2: 443.90999999999985,
      3: -75.320000000000164,
      4: 276.24999999999989}})
```

I want to add up the number of profitable years, where `p1_profit` represents profit for year `1` and so on, across the columns for each row.

I tried to do something like:

```
np.sign(df[df.p1_profit > 0].p1_profit) + \
np.sign(df[df.p2_profit > 0].p2_profit) + \
np.sign(df[df.p3_profit > 0].p3_profit)
```

result:

```
0   NaN
2   NaN
4   NaN
dtype: float64
```

The issue is that the result of each `np.sign(X)` has its own index that may be different than the result of the others calls to `np.sign(X)`.

The desired result should be where `row 0` has `1` year that are profitable, `row 1` has `0-` years that are profitable and so on.

```
row 0: 1
row 1: 0
row 2: 2
row 3: 0
row 4: 1
```

Comment: @DSM - just updated.

Comment: @JohnGalt - BINGO! you are correct. :-) Thank you. That works perfect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `sum` on boolean result.

```
In [7]: (df > 0).sum(axis=1)
Out[7]:
0    1
1    0
2    2
3    0
4    1
dtype: int64
```